# Error Cannot resolve Assembly MediaCapture

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I've made this [Microsoft example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj872764.aspx). The C++ library successfully compiled. The problems start when I compile the application Windows RunTime. I have next error:

```
Error   1   Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.Media.winmd'  C:\...\MediaCapture.csproj  MediaCapture
```

What's the problem? This is the official example of Microsoft, which should run without problems.

Comment: What project template have you used? Did you mean to tag the question as C# 5.0?

Comment: I speak about C# Blank App (XAML)